# Angular.js + Bootstrap: how to show all views on vertical scroll?

Tags: angularjs, mobile, singlepage

I'm building my first Angular.js + Bootstrap web site.
As far as user interface is concerned, I use a classical *top navbar* approach, with 7/8 items in navbar linking to the relative views. [This](http://marcolino.github.io/bb/#/) is a first version of the site. When you click on "weather", you go to the weather page. When You click on "services", you go to the services page. That's ok.

But, I would like, for a better mobile user experience, when scrolling down, all views to be shown, in sequence... [This](http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0J8150B) is an example of what I mean, to be clearer...

Is it possible, preserving the angular.js "routing" logic?

**UPDATE**: I did change the page contents in the first link, adding two links in navbar, because of Ronni Skansing comment...

**UPDATE2**: I try to better reformulate the question:
*Is it possible, with angular.js (+bootstrap), to design an UI with all views reachable without any click, but continuously, vertical scrolling the page, the way a typical mobile web app user is used to?*

Comment: The example has no need for real routing. Put a anchor tag, reference it and use js to make the scroll smooth..

Comment: Yes, sorry... Probably you say this because there was only one link in nav... I did just add two more, just to clarify my question... I would like that a vertical scroll on the "services" page should take to the "weather", and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can really have a single page unless you design your website to be a single page.

Anyway, I found a solution which is very similar to what you would like: simply add a transition on `ng-view` change. The user won't be able to scroll, it will still have to click on the navbar items. But the sensation will be similar to scrolling. See here the [example.](http://dfsq.github.io/ngView-animation-effects/app/#/page/3) (remember to choose the slidedown effect)

Comment: Thanks for your answer: this is a good idea, I didn't think about it... Though, it's not a real solution to my question: what I did ask (probably it was not so clear in my question, I will update it right now...) was: "Is it possible, with angular.js (+bootstrap), to design an UI with all views reachable without any click, but continuously, vertical scrolling the page, the way a typical mobile web app user is used to?". Your suggestion is a good workaround, but I ask for a real solution, or for a statement that explains why a solution is not possible...

Comment: Well, my first statement is that you can't do it unless you do it. That is, there is no way to compact the classic angularjs routing in a single page. If you really want to do it and my workaround is not enough, maybe you could try using nested views: try to look at [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), but personally I've never used it.

Comment: I did look ad ui-router... it defines "states", which are bound to named, nested and parallel views... No way - as far as I can understand - to "scroll" from one view to the next one... :-(

Comment: Just one thought: should it be imaginable to bind a method to a scroll-down event which - if at the bottom of current view - routes to the next one? Could I obtain an effect similar to the one I mention in the question (http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0J8150B) ?

Comment: I thought you could use nested views in the following way: create a "global" view, and nest all your views inside the global, one below the other. Than it's just a matter of scrolling. I don't know if ui-router allows to nest more than one view, you need to read the documentation and play around a little. Imho, if it can do it then it's the way to go. As far as binding to scroll is concerned, it is generally a bad idea, because of a number of problems (scroll events are fired a lot, scrolling creates expectations into users, and so on).

Comment: I suppose you did persuade me to avoid using scroll (at bottom) event to switch to next view... Sorry before accepting I will wait for an answer to my question (as formulated in the last update), since I don't yet get why it's not possible to produce a "one-page" app (example here: http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0J8150B) with angular routeProvider logic...

Comment: No problem, maybe someone knows a better solution. Even if yesterday I was thinking...what if you really create a single page from all your templates and for each section you specify the controller? You would have the scrolling and keep the controllers you already have.

Comment: Yes... But, would it mean you have to load *all* the views on first page load? I suppose answer is yes... What impact would this have on performance?

Comment: It really depends on a lot of factors: number of DOM elements, complexity of operations in the controllers...but if you want a single page there is really no magic that can give you that without actually putting everything in a single page. If you really want at this point the only solution is the animated transition between views, together with a change of view on vertical scroll. As long as scrolling is limited to the switch, it should be doable, even if I personally hate binding to the window scroll event.

Comment: I do not really want to do it, I would rather like to undertand as many implications as possible... I really like the one page - veritcal scroll approach, but probably - as you say - it fits well only for simple and light web sites...

Comment: Remember also that generally phones have less memory, so loading too much data can result in a clunky experience. Personally I see no problem in putting a well-made responsive menu. Bootstrap navbar is already there, works well, and you can customize it as you want. Than you can add transitions to make the experience smoother/nicer.